# Entity Framework Core - combination between two many-to-many relationships

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have 3 classes a `User` can have multiple `GroupedResources`, and `GroupedResources` can have multiple `Resource`

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupedResources> GroupedResources { get; set; }
}
    
public class GroupedResources
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}
    
public class Resource
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual GroupedResources GroupedResources { get; set; }
}
```

In `Context` class

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        entity.HasMany<GroupedResources>().WithOne(x => x.User);
    });
               
    modelBuilder.Entity<GroupedResources>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        entity.HasMany<Resource>().WithOne(x => x.GroupedResource);
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Resource>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    });    
}
```

Ef Core create incorrect table and connections between the objects

Comment: Can a grouped resource have more than one user? Can a resource be in more than one grouped resource?

Comment: @SBFrancies a resource can be in many grouped resource and a grouped resource can be for many users

Comment: Then you have two many to many relationships, not one to many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Let's add foreign keys so that the entity can create more precise relationships:

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupedResources> GroupedResources { get; set; }
}
    
public class GroupedResources
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}
    
public class Resource
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual GroupedResources GroupedResources { get; set; }
}
```

`Context` class will be like this

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        entity.HasMany(x => x.GroupedResources)
            .WithOne(x => x.User)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    });
               
    modelBuilder.Entity<GroupedResources>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        entity.HasMany(x => x.Resources)
            .WithOne(x => x.GroupedResource)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.GroupId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    });
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<Resource>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    });    
}
```

Comment: already tried this way, I already have User and Resource table, so this migration added two columns GroupReourceId and GroupedReourcesId to Reource table and create new table with fields Id, userId and userId1

Comment: you have to specify the property of N-1 of the foreign key, I have updated the answer